customer name in dropdownsearch pkge shows first 20 names at first i need if word is searched it needs to be searchin api and retrievename dynamically
 Future<List<ProductModel>> getcustomer(String filter, BuildContext context) async {
    print('Searching with filter: $filter');  // Debugging line

    final data = Provider.of<MaterialPickupProvider>(context, listen: false);

    // Make API call
    await data.FetchCalibrationcustomer(filter);

    print('Fetched customers: ${data.fetchcustomer.length}'); // Debugging line

    return data.fetchcustomer; // Returning fetched customers
  }

 Consumer<MaterialPickupProvider>(builder: (context,calibprov,child){

              return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0.w),
              //   height: 5.0.h,
              width: 70.0.w,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black45, // Set border color here
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0), // Optional: Set border radius
              ),
              child: DropdownSearch<ProductModel>(
                popupProps: PopupProps.menu(
                  showSearchBox: true,
                ),

                asyncItems: (String filter) => getcustomer(filter, context), // Calls getcustomer for every search
                itemAsString: (ProductModel u) => u.name, // Converts ProductModel to a displayable string
                onChanged: (ProductModel? data) {
                  // Handle selection if needed
                  print('Selected customer: ${data?.name}');
                },
                dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
                  dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: calibprov.createcustomername ?? "Contact Person",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12.sp,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12.sp,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              );
              }),

  List<ProductModel> _fetchcustomer = [];

  List<ProductModel> get fetchcustomer => _fetchcustomer;

  Future<ProductModel?> FetchCalibrationcustomer(String searchText) async {
    try {
      final response = await client.searchRead(
          "res.partner",
          [
            ['name', 'ilike', searchText],
          ],
          [
            'id',
            'name',
          ],
          context: {},
          limit: 20);

      print("result= " + response.getResult().toString());

      final extractedData = response.getResult()['records'];
      print(extractedData);
      final List<ProductModel> category = [];

      extractedData.forEach((value) {
        category.add(ProductModel(
          value['id'],
          value['name'],
        ));
      });
      _fetchcustomer = category;

      print("||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||");
      print(category);
      print("||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||");

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      throw (error);
    }
  }


partner name has above 1000 customer names at first customer name has 20 names when I search in the dropdown search box from each word it needs to call API and retrieve results up to 20 directly but now its just retrieves 20 names at first when searching its searches only from first downloaded 20 names.

You can use isFilterOnline: true  a property of PopupProps.menu(...)

you can use Autocomplete Widget from flutter (built in)
just like the following example
class DropdownSearch<T extends DropAble> extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController textController;
  final List<T> items;
  final void Function(T) onSuggestionSelected;
  final bool required;
  final String placeHolder;
  final String label;
  final String? Function(T?) validator;

  const DropdownSearch({
    super.key,
    required this.textController,
    required this.items,
    required this.onSuggestionSelected,
    this.required = false,
    this.label = "",
    this.placeHolder = "",
    required this.validator,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            "${required ? "* " : ""}$label",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 14,
          ),
          RawAutocomplete<String>(
            optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
            return  items.map((e)=>e.name ?? "").toList()
                  .where((item) =>
                  (item).toLowerCase().contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()))
                  .toList();
            },
            onSelected: (String selection) {
              textController.text = selection;
              T? item = items.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element.name == selection);
              if (item != null) {
                onSuggestionSelected(item);
              }
            },
            fieldViewBuilder: (
                BuildContext context,
                TextEditingController textEditingController,
                FocusNode focusNode,
                VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted,
                ) {
              return TextFormField(
                controller: textEditingController,
                decoration:  InputDecoration(
                  hintText: placeHolder,
                ),
                focusNode: focusNode,
                onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                  T? item = items.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element.name == value);
                  onFieldSubmitted();
                  if (item != null) {
                    onSuggestionSelected(item);
                  }
                },
               // validator: vali,
              );
            },
            optionsViewBuilder: (
                BuildContext context,
                AutocompleteOnSelected<String> onSelected,
                Iterable<String> options,
                ) {
              return Align(
                alignment: Get.locale?.languageCode == "ar" ? Alignment.topRight : Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Material(
                  elevation: 4.0,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: Get.width-70,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      itemCount: options.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        final  option = options.elementAt(index);
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            textController.text = option;
                            onSelected(option);
                            T? item = items.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element.name == option);
                            if(item != null){
                              onSuggestionSelected(item);
                            }
                          },
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(option),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 14,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

